# R reads %d%b%Y date's month in wrong language

Tags: r, date, format

I am running a code my colleague has written on his Rstudio some time ago and I am stuck on what appears to be a very silly problem. I have a variable in a dataframe that is a character and represents a date, such as

```
30jan2016
38feb2016
```

I need to transform this character string into a date variable and I am using the following:

```
df$newvar <- format(as.Date(df$oldvar, format="%d%b%Y"), format="%Y%m%d")
```

This is what I get:

```
NA
2016-02-28
```

After some though I realised that my Rstudio is reading the "month" part of the string in Italian (below you can find the comparison of month abbreviations ENG-ITA), and is correctly decoding only what it can read in ITALIAN. Changing global language options didn't help (and anyway R language was already set to English). Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
ENG    ITA
jan    gen
feb    feb
mar    mar
apr    apr
may    mag
jun    giu
jul    lug
aug    ago
sep    set
oct    ott
nov    nov
dec    dic
```

NOTE: Of course I could replace parts of the string and then run the piece of code, but I need this code to run on ANY computer, in English.

Comment: What day is `38feb2016` ?

Comment: What's the output of `Sys.getlocale()`? You probably need to change your locale with `Sys.setlocale()`. E.g: `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_GB.UTF-8")`

Comment: @Jaap that did the job, thanks. If you post your comment as an answer I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 3):

Try `readr`. There is a possibility to manually set the locale.

```
library(readr)
parse_date(c("30jan2016", "1feb2017"), "%d%b%Y", locale = locale("en"))
```

Comment: `Error in locale("en") : could not find function "locale"`